# java.lang.NullPointerException when reading from a text file

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am working on a coursework and I'm facing an exception when I try to load from a text file.

I am trying to store the IDs and the Questions.

The output should be :

```
{285 = Fill in the blank. A Node is generally defined inside another class, making it a(n) ____ class. }
{37 = How would you rate your programming skills?}
```

This is inside the textfile :

```
258 MC
Question
Fill in the blank. A Node is generally defined inside another class, making it a(n) ____ class.
Answer
Private
Inner
Public
Internal
Selected
2

37 L5
Question
How would you rate your programming skills?
Answer
Excellent
Very good
Good
Not as good as they should be
Poor
Selected
-1
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

 try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("questions.txt"))) {


  Map < Integer, String > map = new HashMap < Integer, String > ();
  String line = br.readLine();


  while (line != null) {
   String[] temp;

   temp = line.split(" ");
   int id = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);

   line = br.readLine();
   line = br.readLine();

   String question = line;
   line = br.readLine();
   line = br.readLine();

   while (line.trim() != ("Selected")) {

    line = br.readLine();

   }

   line = br.readLine();
   int selected = Integer.parseInt(line);
   line = br.readLine();

   map.put(id, question);
   System.out.println(map);
  }
 }

}
```

When running the code I'm getting :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   daos.test.main(test.java:47) C:\Users\droop\Desktop\DSA\New
>   folder\dsaCW2Template\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1076: The following
>   error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Users\droop\Desktop\DSA\New
>   folder\dsaCW2Template\nbproject\build-impl.xml:830: Java returned: 1
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition of the `while` loop beginning with

```
while (line.trim() != ("Selected")) {
  ...
```

is always met, so you end up reading off the end of the file.  `line` eventually becomes `null` and `line.trim()` gets an NPE.

Never compare strings with `==` or `!=; use String.equals() instead:

```
while (!line.trim().equals("Selected")) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix Your inner while condition

```
while (line != null && line.trim() != ("Selected")) {

   line = br.readLine();

}
```

And improve your logic for getting right output.

Comment: Ouch. Replaces one mistake by another....